# How to have a text display of your current location on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, gis

Entry question on what to do / where to look further for this possibly easy facility for a Website

I basically want to show the my current geographic location via a text display, not as a display on Google Maps. Obviously I would like this to update automatically

Does anyone know a program that would facilitate this? Or generally the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to update your page with the current location:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing. How do I show that location in text, is it simple to convert?

Comment: I put the code in with the divs and it's blank. Sorry I'm not so hot on javascript

Comment: @aaron_m12345 Did you try this in a mobile device with location access?

Comment: I'm trying this from a mac book

Comment: Well, I am not sure how mobile it is but when I checked it served from a HTTP Web Server (WAMP) on my mobile, it showed me the correct lat and long, every place I moved. `:D`

Comment: Ah nice! I'm just after the country even. I'm not sure if that's difficult or not